# Exploding empty string to array in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to find why I am getting the `comma` when trying to add `$item` to the `$str` while it is empty. The result is like

> ,mu-16

but it is fine while for example I have  `$str ="mu-16,m-13";` as expected. How can I fix this to not add comma to the `$newstr` when the `$str` is empty

```
// $str ="mu-16,m-13";
$str ="";
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$item = "mu-16";
 if (($key = array_search($item, $arr)) !== false) {
     echo "Item is already in list";
 }
 else{
    array_push( $arr,$item);
    $newstr = implode (",", $arr);
    echo $newstr;
}
```

Comment: Because exploding an empty string at the comma, created an array with one element (containing an empty string) already …

Comment: So how can I prevent this?

Comment: Initialize `$arr` as an empty array, when the input string is empty; explode it at the comma otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you explode the empty string you get an array with one empty string `[""]`
When you implode the array the first element is that empty string so it gets a comma after that empty string.

So you can use [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/preg_split) with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` instead of `explode()` giving you an empty array `[]`.

```php
$arr = preg_split ('/,/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

You could also loop through the array and remove empty strings.

```php
$arr = explode(',', $str);
foreach($arr as $i => $v){
  if(empty($v)){
    unset($arr[$i]); 
  }
}
```

Or you could use [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) on the imploded string to remove the NUL-byte and the comma:

```php
$newstr = implode (",", $arr);
$trimmed = ltrim($newstr, "\0,");
echo $trimmed;
```

Comment: Deprecated: preg_split(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($limit) of type int is deprecated