# Deprecated: preg_split():

Tags: php, deprecated, preg-split

I have this code for current url:

```
$core = preg_split('@/@', str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))), NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

On php 8.1.x the problem in this line say:

> "Deprecated: preg_split(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($limit)"

I would appreciate some help to fix the problem in my code.

The original code is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075147/3673405

Comment: Has this question been asked on Stack Overflow before?  Did you read the manual?  Did you try -1?

Comment: Do a browser search for the word "preg_split" on the dupe target.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276529/2943403